# SalesForce Bulk API: Relationship between custom object and Account

Tags: salesforce

I have a custom object in SalesForce called Deal, which is a child of the built-in Account object.  I am trying to use the Bulk XML API to upload a batch of records, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify this relationship correctly.  From the documentation it says that you should reference a custom object's relationships like so:

```
<Relationship__r>
   <sObject>
      <some_indexed_field>#####</some_indexed_field>
   </sObject>
</Relationship__r>
```

If you have any idea how to specify a relationship to the Account object from a custom object I'd really appreciate it.

**Added**

The Deal object has the following 2 fields:

- DealID

  - API Name - DealID__c
  - Data Type - Text(255)(External ID)(Unique Case Sensitive)
- Account

  - API Name - Account__c
  - Data Type - Master-Detail(Account)

Request XML:
`<Account__r>

<sObject>

<ID>0013000000kcWpfAAE</ID>

</sObject>

</Account__r>`

Result XML:
`<result>

<errors>

<message>Field name provided, Id is not an External ID or indexed field for Account</message>

<statusCode>INVALID_FIELD</statusCode>

</errors>

<success>false</success>

<created>false</created>

</result>`

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug and you have to strip out all whitespace and newlines when dealing with reference objects.

Check out:

http://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000ITQ7AAO

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/index_Left.htm#CSHID=datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/datafiles_xml_rel_fields.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

```
<RelationshipName>
<sObject>
    <IndexedFieldName>rwilliams@salesforcesample.com</IndexedFieldName>
</sObject>
```

Everything looks good, but instead of using "ID" for the Indexed Field Name, you need to use "Account__c".  That should take care of your issue.